# Average sum with start end end date

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm working with SQL Teradata and I have a table as such:

```
cust_id start_dt    end_dt      amount  is_current_y_n
12345   1/8/2018    7/8/2018    7044    N
12345   7/9/2018    7/10/2018   8142    N
12345   7/11/2018   7/13/2018   7643    N
12345   7/14/2018   7/14/2018   8630    N
12345   7/14/2018   7/19/2018   5597    N
12345   7/20/2018   12/31/9999  5680    Y
```

Another case that I've seen:

```
cust_id start_dt    end_dt      amount  is_current_y_n
54321   1/1/2015    12/31/9999  8650    Y
```

I need to calculate with SQL the average amount for the past:

```
7 days
30 days
90 days
180 days
```

"Average", meaning that if during the past 7 days the amount changed from 1000 to 2000 in the 3rd day, the average should be:

(1000x3 + 2000x4)/7

I tried to join the table with a date table but it's not very efficient.

Is there any efficient way to achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'average' in this context? For example, if a record is only active for 3 days in the last 7, what would it contribute? Also, you need to show what queries you have tried so far.

Comment: Have you already tried to solve that on your own? If so, please post your (non working) query. That way, you will learn much more. Additionally, the question will not just read like "please do my work".

Answer (score 2):

It can probably be done via Recursive Common Table Expression Query. 
To unfold those date ranges.
With the amounts for each date, the CTE can be joined back to the table to get those averages.

I couldn't test the SQL on a TeraData *(don't have it)*.
But it should almost work on that RDBMS *(probably)*

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE (cust_id, dt, amount, start_dt, end_dt) AS 
(
  SELECT cust_id, start_dt as dt, amount, start_dt,
  case when end_dt - start_dt > 4200 then start_dt else end_dt end
  FROM table_as_such
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cust_id, dt+1, amount, start_dt, end_dt
  FROM CTE
  WHERE dt < end_dt
)
SELECT t.cust_id, t.start_dt
, ROUND(AVG(case when CTE.dt between t.start_dt - 7 and t.start_dt then CTE.amount end),2) as avg7
, ROUND(AVG(case when CTE.dt between t.start_dt - 30 and t.start_dt then CTE.amount end),2) as avg30
, ROUND(AVG(case when CTE.dt between t.start_dt - 90 and t.start_dt then CTE.amount end),2) as avg90
, ROUND(AVG(case when CTE.dt between t.start_dt - 180 and t.start_dt then CTE.amount end),2) as avg180
FROM table_as_such t
JOIN CTE ON (CTE.cust_id = t.cust_id AND CTE.dt between t.start_dt - 180 and t.start_dt)
GROUP BY t.cust_id, t.start_dt
ORDER BY t.cust_id, t.start_dt;
```

Sample Data Used:

```
create table table_as_such (id int not null primary key, cust_id int, start_dt date, end_dt date, amount int, is_current_y_n char(1));
insert into table_as_such values (1,12345,'2018-01-08','2018-07-08',7044,'N');
insert into table_as_such values (2,12345,'2018-07-09','2018-07-10',8142,'N');
insert into table_as_such values (3,12345,'2018-07-11','2018-07-13',7643,'N');
insert into table_as_such values (4,12345,'2018-07-14','2018-07-14',8630,'N');
insert into table_as_such values (5,12345,'2018-07-14','2018-07-19',5597,'N');
insert into table_as_such values (6,12345,'2018-07-20','9999-12-31',5680,'Y');
```

Comment: @DavidKon So does this work on TeraData?  I couldn't find any free online test database for TeraData (as you can find for MySql, MsSql, Postgres, ...). Nor do I wish to install such a monster on my laptop.  So I only knew it would work 'in theory'.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the temporal feature of Teradata can help you in this case. This is due to the PERIOD datatyp and the function to expand.

check this example for this feature and your intention:

```
database demo;

create table demoDateExpand (
  myID integer
 ,myUser VARCHAR(100)
 ,myAmount DECIMAL(10,2)
 ,startDT DATE
 ,endDT   DATE
) no primary index;

insert into demoDateExpand values (1, 'User01', 2.5, '2018-01-01', '2018-01-05');
insert into demoDateExpand values (2, 'User01', 3.0, '2018-01-08', '2018-01-15');
insert into demoDateExpand values (3, 'User01', 1.5, '2018-01-11', '2018-01-25');
insert into demoDateExpand values (4, 'User02', 2.0, '2018-01-01', '2018-01-15');
insert into demoDateExpand values (5, 'User02', 2.5, '2018-01-05', '2018-01-25');
insert into demoDateExpand values (6, 'User02', 4.5, '2018-01-26', '2018-01-27');
insert into demoDateExpand values (7, 'User03', 1.0, '2018-01-10', '2018-01-15');
insert into demoDateExpand values (8, 'User03', 3.5, '2018-01-16', '2018-01-25');

select myID
      ,myUser
      ,myAmount
      ,startDT
      ,endDT
      ,period(startDT, endDT)
  from demoDateExpand
;


select myID
      ,myUser
      ,myAmount
      ,BEGIN(myDate)
  from demoDateExpand
  expand on period(startDT, endDT) AS myDate BY ANCHOR DAY
  order by myID, myDate
;
```

Comment: Thanks! @LukStorms answer was the best result!

Comment: Been a long time that I had to play on a Teradata. So that EXPAND ON PERIOD method is new to me. But that seems such a cool feature to have! Darn, they should add something like that to the SQL Standard. Along with QUALIFY. (I do miss that clause in other RDMBS sometimes)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create my own query with the help of a table with dates:

```
2017-07-11
2017-07-12
...
```

My query is:

```
sel 
    c.cust_id
    ,avg(case when c.cal_dt between '2017-07-01' and '2018-01-01' then c.amount end) as avg_180
    ,avg(case when c.cal_dt between '2017-10-01' and '2018-01-01' then c.amount end) as avg_90
    ,avg(case when c.cal_dt between '2017-12-01' and '2018-01-01' then c.amount end) as avg_30
    ,avg(case when c.cal_dt between '2017-12-24' and '2018-01-01' then c.amount end) as avg_7
from
(
sel b.cust_id
    ,a.cal_dt
    ,b.amount
from
(
sel *
from CALENDAR_DAILY_TABLE
where cal_dt between '2017-07-01' and '2018-01-01'
) as a

join

(
sel *
from MY_TABLE
where  (start_dt > '2017-07-01' or end_dt='9999-12-31')
) as b

on  b.start_dt<=a.cal_dt and a.cal_dt<=b.end_dt

) as c
where c.cust_id ='12345'
group by c.cust_id
```

The result is:

```
cust_id     avg_180     avg_90      avg_30      avg_7
12345       1.34        1.34        1.34        1.34
```

Thanks!